# How to set up email notifications to specific accounts when a field is changed?

Tags: google-sheets

If a field is is changed in a row I need an email to be sent to the email that corresponds with the row. For instance say in a row the first field is 1234@gmail.com, the second is a description field and the third is a field that says in progress. I need an email to be sent to that email address when the in progress field is changed by another user

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to

1. Check that the edit was to the 3rd column
2. Get the content of the 1st cell in that row
3. Send an email there.

Here is how: `e.range` is the active range, `offset(0, -2)` means "same row, two cells to the left".

After entering the script in Tools > Script Editor,  add a trigger: from the script editor, go to Resources > Current project's triggers and select the properties "From spreadsheet | On Edit".

```
function notify(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
    var email = e.range.offset(0, -2).getValue();
    if (email) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Row Changed', 'Your row of the spreadsheet was changed.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nothing happens when I do this?